# How to implement CICD in ionic projects

Tags: ionic-framework, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am new to ionic and I want to implement CICD for my ionic app.

But I don’t know how?!

I searched and faced the appflow and I started learning that.

But I realized for using the appflow’s features and facilities, I have to pay a amount but I can’t.

Thank you in advance for guiding me on how to do this

Comment: You need to be more specific, otherwise it is hard to help you. What excactly are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? What error are you getting where?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that offer free plans that can allow you to have CI/CD pipelines for your project. You get some free usage each week/month or it might even be entirely free if your project is opensource.

For example, you might want to have a look at one these two popular options:

- [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)

For circleCI and ionic, here is a configuration example: [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasquenolle/635f844b30392df0dad845d9682d92c5)